# Is it possible to send metrics to prometheus?

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, ambari

I'm running a 3 node k8s cluster where I have a prometheus instance that scrape my services metrics using object like serviceMonitor. In addition to my cluster services metrics, I would like to get metrics from an ambari-server. I know that it is possible to import ambari metrics as a datasource in grafana but I haven't seen anything about Prometheus. My goal would be to have those metrics in Prometheus to set alerts with AlertManager. I also saw that it is possible to write a go program that would expose metrics in the Prometheus format, but I preferred to ask to the community before trying stuffs.. :-)

If anyone had this issue, i would be happy if you cna help !

Answer (score 3):

You can, Prometheus allows to scrape metrics exposed by external services: obviously they need to respect Prometheus format but I saw that [it's possible](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/How-to-configure-Prometheus-JMX-exporter-using-Ambari/td-p/241887).

You have to create static endpoints and related service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: ambari-metrics
  labels:
    app: ambari
subsets:
- addresses:
  - ip: "ambari-external-ip"
ports:
- name: metrics
  port: 9100
  protocol: TCP
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: ambari-metrics-svc
  namespace: your-monitoring-namespace
  labels:
    app: ambari
spec:
  type: ExternalName
  externalName: ambari-external-ip
  clusterIP: ""
  ports:
  - name: metrics
    port: 9100
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 9100
```

And finally, the *ServiceMonitor*:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  name: ambari-metrics-sm
  labels:
    app: ambari
    prometheus: kube-prometheus
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ambari
    namespaceSelector:
      matchNames:
       your-monitoring-namespace
  endpoints:
  - port: metrics
    interval: 30s
```

Obviously, YMMV and can find a detailed guide on this [article](https://devops.college/prometheus-operator-how-to-monitor-an-external-service-3cb6ac8d5acb)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it when I get back to work :-)